# How do you choose the first email address from a dropdown menu without having to know the full email address?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How do you choose the first email address from a dropdown menu without having to know the full email address?

So for example, if the email starts with Bruce Willis I just want it to find B and then Tab.  Any email will do so any letter will do.

```
            _vechRep.inputEmail.Click();
            actions.SendKeys("J");
            actions.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
            actions.Build().Perform();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            _vechRep.AddDriverInBox.Click();
```

Comment: You need to post some HTML otherwise how are we supposed to write code to find the email? You posted some code but there's no context as to what that code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: All I want to know is how can I send a letter in the actions.SendKeys("J") so if for example its J maybe an email with John is there so I want to grab the first one on the drop down menu.  For example as I am a newbie but do I right something like this: `string[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"} etc then `foreach` and `if exists` TAB???

Comment: How will you know what letter the first email starts with? If you post the relevant HTML, we can come up with a locator for the first email address consistently.